# how to make wordpress woocommerce shop phonenumber not required

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In my woocommerce shop I want the phone number not to be a required field.

I tried this to add in functions.php

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'wc_npr_filter_phone', 10, 1 );
function wc_npr_filter_phone( $address_fields ) {
    $address_fields['billing_phone']['required'] = false;
    return $address_fields;
}
```

but this does not work ...

how can I achieve that the phone number is not required?

thanks

Comment: This code just works in WooCommerce… there is something in your theme, in some plugin or in your code customizations that is conflicting. `woocommerce_billing_fields` or `woocommerce_checkout_fields` hooks work to make billing phone number not required normally. You could try to use `woocommerce_default_address_fields` hook with `$address_fields['phone']['required'] = false;`, but if the other hooks don't work, I am not sure that it will work better.

Comment: how can I figure out wheres the issue?

Comment: First make a database backup and backup your themes folder too…Then  try first to remove all other customizations keeping only this one to see if it changes something… 2) If it doesn't change anything, try to disable all plugins except WooCommerce. check and re enable them one by one, checking each time. 3) At last, contact the theme author and open a support ticket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems alright to me! I don't know why you are having this issue. But here's another snippet! check it out

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'woo_not_required_fields', 9999 );

function woo_not_required_fields( $fields ) {

    unset( $fields['billing']['billing_last_name']['required'] ); // that's it
    unset( $fields['billing']['billing_phone']['required'] );

    return $fields;
}
```

Hope this help.